# How to change the chunk size of an Axios stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to download a stream using Axios, currently doing it this way:

```js
const config = {
    responseType: 'stream',
    url: "https://example.com",
    method: "GET",
    maxRedirects: 0,
    decompress: false,
};

const { status, headers, data } = await axios(config);

data.pipe(streamTarget);
```

Which is working perfectly. However I would like (if possible) to change the size of the chunks obtained from the stream by Axios.

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: The answer depends on who exactly has problems with the current chunk size. Does the `streamTarget` need differently sized chunks?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - Yes, it would be preferred to lower the chunk size on some streams and make it higher for other ones. I bumped into a GitHub issue shortly after asking this question here and I saw somebody mentioning that the chunk size is hardcoded in Nodejs? really hope this isn't how it is

Comment: The chunk size of writable stream like `streamTarget` depends on its [`highWaterMark`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#new-streamwritableoptions).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - I thought so but then https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3845#issuecomment-1040832113 confused me a little. `The problem is not the chunk size, it is the highWaterMark.` there is mainly the core of the confusion